# How Can I Set a Custom 'Default View' for a Document Set?

Tags: document-set

I have allowed the Document Set content type in my Document Library, and nested it inside a Folder hierarchy.

I want to have a separate View as the Default when inside of a Document Set inside the library. I don't want users to have to change it themselves.

Is this possible?

The hierarchy is like this:

Document Library\Folder 1 (default view)\Folder 2 (default view)\Document Set instance (docset view)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the desired view is consistent across the Document Sets, you can configure it once when configuring your Document Set content type and all new instances of this Document Set will reflect this.

The settings you're looking for are referred to as the "Welcome Page" settings.

See: [Create and configure a new Document Set content type](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-configure-a-new-document-set-content-type-HA101782461.aspx)

Under the heading "Configure or customize a Document Set content type", steps 10-12 state:

> 10) In the **Welcome Page Columns** section, specify which columns you want to display on the Welcome Page for the Document Set.
>
> 11) In the **Welcome Page** section, click **Customize the Welcome Page** to customize the appearance of the Welcome Page that displays to users for each instance of the Document Set.
>
> 12) If you want to apply these Welcome Page changes to any Document Sets that inherit from this Document Set, select the check box next to **Update the Welcome Page of Document Sets inheriting from this content type**.

Comment: one more piece of data on this. if you create the view you like, then you can go into the VIEW settings and select Folders.  once in there, you can "Show this view: (1) in all folders, (2) in top level folder, or (3) in folders of content type "<select your document set or folder content type>".  this really was the answer to the riddle.

Comment: is there any way to do this programatically?

Answer (score 5):

In the settings for a Document Set you can choose what View to use.

When you click on a Document Set content type in library settings, one of the options is "Document Set settings". The last option in this dialogue allows you to select a defined view on the library that will be used to show the contents of that Document Set.

Comment: Can you expand a little?

Comment: When you click on a Document Set content type in library settings, one of the options is "Document Set settings".  The last option in this dialogue allows you to select a defined view on the library that will be used to show the contents of that Document Set.  I have added an image above as it does not seem to allow them in these comments. (or not - seems I do not have enough reputation to post an image - sorry)

Comment: Thanks. Don't forget you can edit your answer (I have done this for you).

Comment: unfortunately if you've already created libraries, it doesn't automatically update them to display the columns you choose.

Comment: So...if we don't have the document set view "correct" when we create the document sets... we can't reset the view?

Comment: is there any way to do this programatically?