# Create and assign custom view to particular document set using CSOM C#: 2010

Tags: 2010, document-library, csom, view, document-set

I have a Document Library and Document Set within that. Now my requirement is that I want to create a custom view which should be applicable to particular Document Set only.

As I am having large number of Document Library I cannot prefer to go with manual steps.

So I want the way using which I can create and assign custom view to specific Document Sets using CSOM C# in SharePoint 2010.

**Question:**  Is it possible to create and assign custom view to specific document set using CSOM C# in 2010? If yes then please help me for the same.

I have already gone through [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61565/how-can-i-set-a-custom-default-view-for-a-document-set).

The option with **`Welcome Page`** will not help me as all the content types are already configured. And this cannot be configured again.

Comment: looking for the same answer... to define the document set default list view by code